# Pig - Parsing an XML file

Tags: hadoop, user-defined-functions, bigdata, apache-pig

I would like to parse an XML file like this in pig:

```
<person>
    <name>person1</name>
    <exp>blablabla</exp>
    <exp>blablabla</exp>
</person>

<person>
    <name>person2</name>
    <exp>blablabla</exp>
    <exp>blablabla</exp>
    <exp>blablabla</exp>
</person>
```

I already wrote a JAVA program, which produces this output:

- A first file with the mapping between person's names and their id's:

> 1,person1
>
> 2,person2

Then I can use this pig command to load the file into a variable:

> A = load '...' AS (id_person:int, name:chararray);

- A second file to map the persons and their exp

> 1,1,blablabla
>
> 1,2,blablabla
>
> 2,1,blablabla
>
> 2,2,blablabla
>
> 2,3,blablabla

I load the file that way:

> B = load '...' AS (id_person:int, id_exp:int, text:chararray);

I want to do the same thing, but by using only pig. Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Piggybank's org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader to load xml data. I'm not sure I understand what you want to achieve. If the numbers in your output are related to position within the bag (the ids and the 2nd field in the second file), then you can use datafu's bag function Enumerate ( datafu.pig.bags.Enumerate ) to enumerate the elements within the bag and then generate and store them.

Comment: Having trouble finding the piggybank.jar anywhere. Can you provide a URL to a maven repository where I can get it?

Comment: Just discovered that "The Piggy Bank is a place for Pig users to share their functions" on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PiggyBank